# Site recommendation: Stack Overflow or Computer Science.SE?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am very confused about whether to post these types of question on Stack Overflow or Computer Science.SE.

[image: top]
[image: bottom]

I am aware Computer Science is in beta and would like to support it (constructively), I am also studying computer science. However, my questions are usually about coding specifics, but when it is about a programming principle, which site to I go to?

Comment: @jonsca, thanks for the edit, I didn't know what to call them

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: @jonsca do you know the answer bahhahaha :P

Comment: I agree with Makoto, but I don't personally know enough about Code Review to know whether the first one belongs there.

Comment: @jonsca yep, I don't think I know what computer science is, I think I am getting the title of my course mixed up with computer science, I think I'm just learning programming.. omg, I know I look like a complete and utter idiot

Comment: The dumbest question is the one that is never asked.  Don't worry about it, many people have made the same mistake.

Comment: @jonsca I have never had an activity absorb and challenge me and simultaneously make me feel foolish, as programming :)

Comment: hey downvoter pst, I got a good answer by coming here, so ner ner nee ner ner (childish taunt) less rep here, still gives me more real life marks at Uni :P spltttttttt (you know that sticking your tongue out making that blowing raspberry noise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, **neither of those questions relate to Computer Science directly**.  They're both code-driven questions, and don't take into account any of the theory behind computing.

What seems appropriate for [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13534/optimising-for-loops-and-if-statement) is [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), with a little polish - instead of "which is the most efficient way and why", potentially changing it to "could this be made more efficient" would work.

[This question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13357/changing-variables-within-nested-loops) I'm less certain about.  It's definitely not on topic at Code Review, and as written, would get killed in short order on Stackoverflow.  "Don't know how to populate arrays" isn't exactly the sort of question that could be seen as useful or worth much attention/sympathy.  It could do with a rethink - explain what you're attempting to do, what you've attempted, and what you expect to happen, along with the language you're using (it looks like Python, but I could be mistaken).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I seriously feel like a prat, I have no idea what I'm doing sometimes.. ok I will delete this from cs se and comtemplate posting elsewhere, or just hang onto it and see if I can figure it out in the course of my studies.. I'm asking for a short cut tip really.

Comment: I removed the link (as deleted post) and added images.. ty for your help, I realise I do not know what computer science is.. I must investigate this.. I have exams in a few weeks, so will work on these things when they are over.. ty for yr assistance, I appreciate it, it was such a stupid and trivial question, but I don't want to go muddying up other stack sites, I've done enough of that here and on SO!! :)

Comment: Woo hoo ty Makoto, took your advice and have an answer and have learnt something cheers :) http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29206/optimising-if-statement-and-for-loops/29207?noredirect=1#29207